# select self join if only one resulting row

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible/economical to perform a SELF JOIN of a table (for this example, my table called `myTable` has two columns `pk` and `fk`), and return a record if there is only one resulting record?  I am thinking of something like the following, however, `only_one_row()` is a fictional function that would need to be replaced with something real:

```
SELECT fk
FROM myTable as t1
INNER JOIN myTable AS t2 ON t2.fk=t1.fk
WHERE t1.pk=1
AND only_one_row();
```

For instance, if myTable(id,fk) had the following records, only one record is produced, and I which to select the record:

```
1 1
2 1
3 2
```

However, if myTable(id,fk) had the following records, two '1' records are produced, and the select should not return any rows:

```
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 1
```

I could use PHP to do so, but would rather just use SQL if feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `HAVING` clause that counts the results.

```
SELECT fk
FROM myTable as t1
INNER JOIN myTable AS t2 ON t2.fk=t1.fk
WHERE t1.pk=1
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: Assuming I have proper indexes in place, is there any reason this would be an inefficient query in which I would want to use the application to do two queries and then do an IF statement?

Comment: It has to calculate all the results and then filter it, so the efficiency will be the same if you do the IF in the application.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
SELECT fk
FROM myTable as t1
INNER JOIN myTable AS t2 ON t2.fk=t1.fk
WHERE t1.pk=1
GROUP BY fk
HAVING COUNT(fk) = 1
```

Comment: Any reason `COUNT(fk)` is better/worse than `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: There should be no difference as you have only one column in the SELECT clause. However, you may like to read this: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/